# Python regular expression truncate string by special character with one leading space

Tags: python, regex, try-catch

I need to truncate string by special characters '-', '(', '/' with one leading whitespace, i.e. ' -', ' (', ' /'.

how to do that?

```
patterns=r'[-/()]'    
    try: 
        return row.split(re.findall(patterns, row)[0], 1)[0]
    except: 
        return row
```

the above code picked up all special characters but without the leading space.

```
patterns=r'[s-/()]'
```

this one does not work.

Comment: It looks like you want to get a part of the string before the first occurrence of `\s[-(/]` pattern, right? Try `return re.sub(r'\s[-(/].*', '', row)`

Comment: this one works, thank you Wiktor!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to get a part of the string before the first occurrence of `\s[-(/]` pattern.

Use

```
return re.sub(r'\s[-(/].*', '', row)
```

This code will return a part of `row` string without all chars after the first occurrence of a whitespace (`\s`) followed with `-`, `(` or `/` (`[-(/]`).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/P3A5aa/1).

Answer (score 3):

Try this pattern
`patterns=r'^\s[-/()]'`
or remove ^ depending on your needs.

Comment: try patterns=`r'^\s*[-/()]'`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this pattern `patterns = r'\s+-|\s\/|\s\(|\s\)'`